# How do I synchronize my wallet quicker with bitcoins already sent?

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization

I have my first ever Bitcoin wallet, I instantly sent the bitcoins from blockchain.info to my wallet. Without realizing, my wallet is currently (4pm May 8th 2015) 1 year and 42 weeks behind. Is there a way to speed up this process? I need to buy stuff ASAP and I don't want to wait weeks for my wallet to sync. Also, people are suggesting to restart my wallet and download a Torrent from blockchain, will I lose my bitcoins in the process? I'm using Bitcoin Core.

Comment: My wallet was getting a error after 5mins or so from running and now it won't let me open it at all. Giving me a fatal error. PLEASE HELP

Comment: As long as you have the private key you should be fine! Make sure you back that up. If you need to use your coins as quickly as possible, download a lightweight client such as MultiBit and import the private key there to start using them.

Comment: Hard to help if you don't include any further information beyond "a fatal error". What's the exact error message?

Comment: StopNode()
 Corruption: block checksum mismatch
 *** System error while flushing: Database corrupted

Comment: I don't really understand how to find or use a Private Key, also I'm not sure if I'm doing it properly or not but it won't let me import my wallet on blockchain. I'm trying to drag the folder wallet.dat where it tells me to but it just says ''Connection refused''.

Comment: Okay let me rephrase my question... I baught some bitcoins on Localbitcoins then downloaded Bitcoin-qt then instantly sent it to my wallet and now the wallet is corrupted... Is there a way to get them back?

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37309/is-it-possible-to-get-already-sent-bitcoins-from-a-corrupted-wallet

Comment: Make sure you're running 0.10 or later and don't go for the torrent option, that's obsolete and won't be faster.

Comment: Preserve every copy of your `wallet.dat` file that you have made. You need to find one good copy with your private key in it to recover the Bitcoins.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, get a better Internet connection and a faster computer.

You need a better Internet connection because you are downloading the whole blockchain (I guess you're using bitcoin-qt or the like) and it is a few GB.

And you need a faster computer because as you download the blockchain you are processing those transactions and updating your DB, so a faster computer will lower the time needed to process that information.

Until you have downloaded the whole blockchain you won't be able to spend bitcoins with your wallet because it will wait until all transactions have been processed to know the amout of bitcoins remaining in it.