# Is it possible to get already-sent bitcoins from a corrupted wallet?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, localbitcoins

I bought some bitcoins on LocalBitcoins then downloaded Bitcoin-qt then instantly sent it to my wallet and now the wallet is corrupted... Is there a way to get them back?

Comment: How corrupted is it? What are the symptoms of the corruption?

Comment: When I open the wallet it instantly crashes,.

Comment: Also trying to make a backup doesn't work because my wallet.dat is empty

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a backup of your current wallet.dat file. Check [this](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory) is you don't know where the file is stored.
2. Check debug.log in your bitcoin datadir, see if there are any errors, ask somebody, post here, post on IRC
3. Start bitcoind or Bitcoin-Qt with command line argument `-salvagewallet` (if you don't know how to run a Application with command line arguments, try to ask someone or get help over IRC freenode/#bitcoin.
4. If step 3 didn't help, check if you have a backup from your wallet.dat, replace files (only overwrite your wallet.dat if you followed step 1).
5. If nothing worked out, get help from a bitcoin expert over IRC (but never give away your wallet.dat!)

Comment: Alright thank you for the help :) I'll do that and get back if it works

Comment: Okay well, my wallet is now up and running again... Someone suggested to deleted my entire bitcoin folder except my wallet.dat... But I have to wait for it to sync over 3 years. Is there a way to speed this process up? I tried to download the folder on blockchain but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: PS : When I deleted everything except my wallet.dat will the bitcoins still be sent to my wallet once it sync's?

Comment: Correction* I deleted everything except my wallet.dat and my peer.dat

Comment: Yes. If you delete everything except you wallet.dat you should find all you incoming and outgoing transactions after you sync is complete. It might take a while (couple of hours till couple of days depending on you system).